# Helm/ Kubernetes multiple environments only receiving 1 external IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to helm and generally to kubernetes as well, so this could be something super obvious and simple. I'm trying to set up a cluster with multiple environments, one for testing and one for production. I've had no issue getting a single environment working, but at the moment cannot figure out how to get separate external IP addresses for the 2 different environments.

I have the nginx-ingress controller running, and from my understanding from docs and SO, the ingress-service file should direct traffic accordingly, but when I get all svcs, only one external IP is showing which returns a 404. No errors came up when installing the charts, and the frontend/ backend services are running. Just cant seem to find an answer if there is a step I'm missing.

Another thing, and perhaps I've led myself in the wrong direction, the tutorials I've followed to get started with helm skip the ingress, my guess was for simplicity, but my understanding is that its best having the ingress in place, especially for production use. For example, [this example](https://codefresh.io/blog/helm-deployment-environments/) skips the ingress, but gets different endpoints for the single service per environment.

Heres the ingress.yaml template:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: octodemo.net
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
  
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.frontend.service.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.frontend.service.ports.port }}
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .Values.backend.service.name }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.backend.service.ports.port }}
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

and the result of kubectl get svc -A

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.92.0.1      <none>         443/TCP                      20d
demoapp         backend-svc                          ClusterIP      10.92.8.36     <none>         5000/TCP                     8m7s
demoapp         frontend-svc                         ClusterIP      10.92.7.207    <none>         3000/TCP                     8m7s
demotest        test-backend-svcs                    ClusterIP      10.92.1.97     <none>         5000/TCP                     3m39s
demotest        test-frontend-svc                    ClusterIP      10.92.7.164    <none>         3000/TCP                     3m39s
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.92.14.1     34.94.209.65   80:31918/TCP,443:30364/TCP   17d
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.92.1.197    <none>         443/TCP                      17d
kube-system     default-http-backend                 NodePort       10.92.5.251    <none>         80:30582/TCP                 20d
kube-system     kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.92.0.10     <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP                20d
kube-system     metrics-server                       ClusterIP      10.92.12.113   <none>         443/TCP                      20d
```

Comment: The point is not to have multiple IPs per cluster, but have different domains mapped to same IP via DNS and then ingress would sort it out via host matching rules. I recommend starting with K3s and Traefik ingress as that is easier - see my post here on what you need to set up https://worklifenotes.com/2023/08/07/handling-multiple-domains-on-k3s-with-tls/ - also feel free to reach out via https://devopscommunity.org/ Discord for follow up questions.